# How to store a value on WP_option table

Tags: options

```
<?php
function myplugin_register_settings() {
       add_option('marker_pin','');
    register_setting( 'marker_group', 'marker_pin', 'myplugin_callback' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'myplugin_register_settings' );

function myplugin_register_options_page() {
  add_options_page('Google Map', 'Map', 'manage_options', 'Google_map', 'myplugin_options_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin_register_options_page');


function plugin_admin_enqueue_styles() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBPUcMLet39Rn_MXvOJErCbT7VnsOAVPWc&libraries=places&callback=initMap', array('jquery'),'1.0', true );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.0', true );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'code-js', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_admin_enqueue_styles' );



function myplugin_options_page()
{

?>
  <div>
  <?php screen_icon(); ?>
  <h2>My Plugin Page Title</h2>
  <form method="post" action="options.php">
  <?php settings_fields( 'marker_group' ); ?>
  <h3>This is my option</h3>
  <p>Some text here.</p>
  <table>
  <tr valign="top">
  <th scope="row"><label for="marker">City:</label></th>
  <td>
    <?php  $pins = get_option('marker_pin'); ?>
    <div id="pac-container">
        <input id="pac_input" type="text" name="pac_input"
            placeholder="Enter City" value="<?php echo $pins; ?>">
    </div>

  </td>

  </tr>
  </table>
  <?php submit_button(); ?>

  <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
  </form>
  </div>

<?php

}
function update_option_fn()
{
   $name=$_POST['name_palce'];
   echo $name;
   update_option('marker_pin',$name);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_update_option_fn', 'update_option_fn');
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
        function initMap() {

          var input = document.getElementById("pac_input"); 

          var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

          autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {

          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          var placename = place.name;
          input.value=placename;

          if (!place.geometry) {
            alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
          }

        });

      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
         /*$('#pac_input').on('input', function()*/
           $('#pac_input').focusout(function() {
                var Place =  $('#pac_input').val(); 
                console.log(Place);
                $.ajax({
               url: '<?php admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>',
               data: {"action":"update_option_fn","name_palce" :Place},
               /*data: {name_palce :Place},*/
               type: 'POST',
               success:function(data){
                   console.log("success"+data);
               }
              });
            });

            $("#submit").click(function() {
            <?php 
                $id = $_POST['name_palce'];
                update_option('marker_pin',$id,true);

            ?>
          });
        });



</script>
```

This my code, I want to store a value which come from ajax  into wp_option table 
how I can do it????

Comment: this can help you to understand using ajax in admin panel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873537/saving-wordpress-settings-api-options-with-ajax

Comment: I get value form ajax but I want to store that value on database when submit_button() of options page are called

Answer (score 1):

replace your code with as.

```
 <?php
function myplugin_register_settings() 
{
    add_option('marker_pin','');
    register_setting( 'marker_group', 'marker_pin', 'myplugin_callback' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'myplugin_register_settings' );
function myplugin_register_options_page() 
{
    add_options_page('Google Map', 'Map', 'manage_options', 'Google_map', 'myplugin_options_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin_register_options_page');
function plugin_admin_enqueue_styles() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBPUcMLet39Rn_MXvOJErCbT7VnsOAVPWc&libraries=places&callback=initMap', array('jquery'),'1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'code-js', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_admin_enqueue_styles' );
function myplugin_options_page()
{?>
    <div>
        <?php screen_icon(); ?>
        <h2>My Plugin Page Title</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'marker_group' ); ?>
            <h3>This is my option</h3>
            <p>Some text here.</p>
            <table>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="marker">City:</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <?php  $pins = get_option('marker_pin'); ?>
                        <div id="pac-container">
                            <input id="pac_input" type="text" name="pac_input" placeholder="Enter City" value="<?php echo $pins; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
            <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
        </form>
    </div><?php
}
function update_option_fn()
{
    if (isset($_POST['name_palce']) && !empty($_POST['name_palce'])) 
    {
       $name=$_POST['name_palce'];
       echo $name;
       update_option('marker_pin',$name);       
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_update_option_fn', 'update_option_fn');
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
        var place='';
        function initMap() 
        {
            var input = document.getElementById("pac_input");
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() 
            {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                var placename = place.name;
                input.value=placename;
                if (!place.geometry)
                {
                    alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            <?php $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( "my-special-string" );?>
            $('#pac_input').focusout(function() 
            {
                var Place =  $('#pac_input').val(); 
                console.log(Place);

                var wp_sec_data_post = { action: 'update_option_fn', security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>'};
                var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
                wp_sec_data_post2['name_palce'] = Place;
                jQuery.post( ajaxurl, wp_sec_data_post2, function( response ) 
                {
                    console.log("success"+response);                    
                });                
            });
            $("#submit").click(function() 
            {
                var Place =  $('#pac_input').val(); 
                console.log(Place);
                var wp_sec_data_post = { action: 'update_option_fn', security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>'};
                var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
                wp_sec_data_post2['name_palce'] = Place;
                jQuery.post( ajaxurl, wp_sec_data_post2, function( response ) 
                {
                    console.log("success"+response);                    
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```